# Spring Boot JPA @Entity not defined as bean

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I am not able to run my Spring Boot application, because there is an issue with JPA. But I am not able to find the problem and resolve it. I searched for a solution on several stack overflow topics, but not even one solution was helpful for me. I defined the following model:

```
package xyz.blackmonster.window.models;

import java.util.List;

import javax.persistence.CascadeType;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.FetchType;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.OneToMany;
import javax.persistence.OneToOne;

import org.hibernate.annotations.GenericGenerator;

/**
 * Window order
 */
@Entity
public class Order {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "system-uuid")
    @GenericGenerator(name = "system-uuid", strategy = "uuid2")
    private String uuid;
    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy = "order", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<Window> windows;
    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy = "order", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private Service service;
    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy = "order", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private Cost cost;
    @Column(name = "email")
    private String email;

    public String getUuid() {
        return uuid;
    }

    public void setUuid(String uuid) {
        this.uuid = uuid;
    }

    public List<Window> getWindows() {
        return windows;
    }

    public void setWindows(List<Window> windows) {
        this.windows = windows;
    }

    public Service getService() {
        return service;
    }

    public void setService(Service service) {
        this.service = service;
    }

    public Cost getCost() {
        return cost;
    }

    public void setCost(Cost cost) {
        this.cost = cost;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }
}
```

As you can see, the entity uses the right import (javax.persistence.Entity). I am pointing this out, because this was one of the solutions I came across.

I also defined the interface for the repository as follows:

```
package xyz.blackmonster.window.repositories;

import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;

import xyz.blackmonster.window.models.Order;

public interface OrderRepository extends JpaRepository<Order, String> {
}
```

As you can see, the OrderRepository class does not have the @Repository annotation as many examples by googling show.

Several solutions pointed out that the application class needs two additional annotations to find the repositories and scan for entities, since the application class is in package xyz.blackmonster.window.app and the entities are in xyz.blackmonster.window.models:

```
package xyz.blackmonster.window.app;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.domain.EntityScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.EnableJpaRepositories;

@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan("xyz.blackmonster.window")
@EnableJpaRepositories("xyz.blackmonster.window.repositories")
@EntityScan("xyz.blackmonster.window.repositories")
public class WindowAppApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(WindowAppApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

I have both the @EnableJpaRepositories("xyz.blackmonster.window.repositories") and @EntityScan("xyz.blackmonster.window.repositories") set. Even having all this configuration set, running Spring Boot fails. I get the following stack trace:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'orderRestController' defined in file [/Users/jklancic/Development/personal/window-app/build/classes/java/main/xyz/blackmonster/window/pages/OrderRestController.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'orderServiceImpl' defined in file [/Users/jklancic/Development/personal/window-app/build/classes/java/main/xyz/blackmonster/window/services/OrderServiceImpl.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'orderRepository': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not a managed type: class xyz.blackmonster.window.models.Order
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:732) ~[spring-beans-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:197) ~[spring-beans-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1267) ~[spring-beans-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1124) ~[spring-beans-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:535) ~[spring-beans-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:495) ~[spring-beans-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:317) ~[spring-beans-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) ~[spring-beans-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:315) ~[spring-beans-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) ~[spring-beans-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:759) ~[spring-beans-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:869) ~[spring-context-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:550) ~[spring-context-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:140) ~[spring-boot-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar:2.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:780) [spring-boot-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar:2.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:412) [spring-boot-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar:2.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:333) [spring-boot-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar:2.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1277) [spring-boot-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar:2.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1265) [spring-boot-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar:2.0.5.RELEASE]
    at xyz.blackmonster.window.app.WindowAppApplication.main(WindowAppApplication.java:16) [main/:na]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'orderServiceImpl' defined in file [/Users/jklancic/Development/personal/window-app/build/classes/java/main/xyz/blackmonster/window/services/OrderServiceImpl.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'orderRepository': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not a managed type: class xyz.blackmonster.window.models.Order
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:732) ~[spring-beans-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:197) ~[spring-beans-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1267) ~[spring-beans-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1124) ~[spring-beans-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:535) ~[spring-beans-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:495) ~[spring-beans-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:317) ~[spring-beans-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) ~[spring-beans-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:315) ~[spring-beans-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) ~[spring-beans-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:251) ~[spring-beans-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1135) ~[spring-beans-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1062) ~[spring-beans-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:818) ~[spring-beans-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:724) ~[spring-beans-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    ... 19 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'orderRepository': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not a managed type: class xyz.blackmonster.window.models.Order
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1699) ~[spring-beans-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:573) ~[spring-beans-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:495) ~[spring-beans-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:317) ~[spring-beans-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) ~[spring-beans-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:315) ~[spring-beans-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) ~[spring-beans-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:251) ~[spring-beans-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1135) ~[spring-beans-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1062) ~[spring-beans-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:818) ~[spring-beans-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:724) ~[spring-beans-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    ... 33 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not a managed type: class xyz.blackmonster.window.models.Order
    at org.hibernate.metamodel.internal.MetamodelImpl.managedType(MetamodelImpl.java:473) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar:5.2.17.Final]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaMetamodelEntityInformation.<init>(JpaMetamodelEntityInformation.java:74) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.0.10.RELEASE.jar:2.0.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaEntityInformationSupport.getEntityInformation(JpaEntityInformationSupport.java:66) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.0.10.RELEASE.jar:2.0.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactory.getEntityInformation(JpaRepositoryFactory.java:180) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.0.10.RELEASE.jar:2.0.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactory.getTargetRepository(JpaRepositoryFactory.java:118) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.0.10.RELEASE.jar:2.0.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactory.getTargetRepository(JpaRepositoryFactory.java:101) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.0.10.RELEASE.jar:2.0.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport.getRepository(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:304) ~[spring-data-commons-2.0.10.RELEASE.jar:2.0.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.lambda$afterPropertiesSet$4(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:290) ~[spring-data-commons-2.0.10.RELEASE.jar:2.0.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.util.Lazy.getNullable(Lazy.java:141) ~[spring-data-commons-2.0.10.RELEASE.jar:2.0.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.util.Lazy.get(Lazy.java:63) ~[spring-data-commons-2.0.10.RELEASE.jar:2.0.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.afterPropertiesSet(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:293) ~[spring-data-commons-2.0.10.RELEASE.jar:2.0.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(JpaRepositoryFactoryBean.java:102) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.0.10.RELEASE.jar:2.0.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1758) ~[spring-beans-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1695) ~[spring-beans-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    ... 44 common frames omitted
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: Remove all your annotation and leave the `@SpringBootApplication` annotation on the `WindowAppApplication`. Move it to the top level package of your application, in this case `xyz.blackmonster.window` (as recommended by the Spring Boot team!) and restart your application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the problem. I defined the wrong package class for the entities. The application should have the entity scan set to *xyz.blackmonster.window.**models*** and not the package, where I have the repositories defined.

Here is the fixed code:

```
package xyz.blackmonster.window.app;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.domain.EntityScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.EnableJpaRepositories;

@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan("xyz.blackmonster.window")
@EnableJpaRepositories("xyz.blackmonster.window.repositories")
@EntityScan("xyz.blackmonster.window.models")
public class WindowAppApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(WindowAppApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The simple solution is here..

Move your `WindowAppApplication` class to base package: `xyz.blackmonster.window` instead of under app and use below, Spring boot will do everything for you magically..

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class WindowAppApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(WindowAppApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

Comment: I found the problem and added my own answer. With Spring Boot I could do that, then the scanning would start at the root level/package. But I do not want that. I resolve the issue by setting the right package for models - @EntityScan("xyz.blackmonster.window.models"). That was my issue. I was pointing towards the wrong package to scan for entities.